# 2sxc: deny permissions to user editor to change layout

Tags: 2sxc

Working with user permission, I would like to deny to editors users possibility to change layout of a 2sxc app module. Is it possible? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout-switch is a very basic functionality which "normal" editors usually need.

A simple trick to "disable" it is to go to all the layouts and set them to hidden - that way users cannot switch to them any more. If ever you need to do a manual switch, you could then un-hide it, switch, and hide it again.

Comment: Thanks you! I need this cause I would give a user permission to only add/modify content, so he would not have possibility to modify layout. Unfortunatly this will not disable the edit option Change layout/template in the DNN edit menu https://snag.gy/ftQGFd.jpg

Comment: Anyway, I just tried, and even hiding them my layout are still all visible in the drop down menu of change layout functionality. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe there is a bug in a newer version accidentally showing the hidden ones - just opened an issue: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1014